# MySQL problem! Needs to select unique value from one row only

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm creating this app where it's important to register if a person is active or not on the current day. My table structure looks like this:

```
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment | 
| kid_id    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                | 
| status    | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL              |                | 
| timestamp | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
```

What's important for me; is to select only values with timestamp equal to the current day. Next I need to check if the latest status is "active" or "inactive" of course based on kid_id. What I've figured out so far is this.

```
SELECT kid_id , status , timestamp FROM actions WHERE date(timestamp) = CURDATE() ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Which returns these values:

```
+--------+----------+---------------------+
| kid_id | status   | timestamp           |
+--------+----------+---------------------+
|      4 | active   | 2010-08-23 12:10:03 | 
|      3 | inactive | 2010-08-23 10:53:18 | 
|      3 | active   | 2010-08-23 10:53:10 | 
+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

Only problem now is that i receive both the active and inactive status with "kid_id" = "3".
So my question is how do i only select the latest status from each kid_id.

In advance thank you very much for your help. It's appreciated.

**---------- EDIT**

I'll try to make my point a little more clear.

This is my table as it looks right now...

```
+--------+----------+---------------------+
| kid_id | status   | timestamp           |
+--------+----------+---------------------+
|      3 | inactive | 2010-08-23 18:32:19 | 
|      4 | active   | 2010-08-23 12:10:03 | 
|      3 | active   | 2010-08-23 10:53:10 | 
+--------+----------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to retrieve these values and only these

```
|      3 | inactive | 2010-08-23 18:32:19 | 
|      4 | active   | 2010-08-23 12:10:03 |
```

All of the solutions suggested below returns these values:

```
|      4 | active   | 2010-08-23 12:10:03 | 
|      3 | active   | 2010-08-23 10:53:10 |
```

By the way... Thanks for all the responses so soon I'm really grateful for all the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been out the office today. In the mean time I've figured out a way to solve my problem. I used a subselect which worked.

In the end my code looks a little like **ovais.tariq**'s

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT * 
            FROM (
                SELECT * FROM actions 
                AS a
                WHERE date(timestamp) = curdate() 
                AND timestamp = (
                    SELECT max(timestamp) 
                    FROM actions 
                    AS b
                    WHERE a.kid_id = b.kid_id
                    )
                )
            AS c
```

Thanks everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

first, your WHERE-clause should read

```
WHERE ... AND status = 'active'
```

If you can have different rows for a single user on a given day that are set to active, you can say

```
SELECT DISTINCT kid, status ...
```

Note that this returns unique values for everything you select, so you shouldn't select the timestamp because different timestamps at the same day, for the same user, would again show up as several rows (as they're non-distinct)

Comment: If i understand your code correct this only returns the active kids and not the inactive kids. If I sort by timestamp your i get the values all right but I still can't eliminate that last active status for kid_id 3... Correct me if any of this sounds wrong.

Comment: ah ok I got it wrong as well, sorry. then shamittomar's code should be doing what you want

Answer (score 1):

this should do

```
SELECT a1.*
FROM actions AS a1 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT kid_id, MAX(`timestamp`) AS `timestamp` 
                 FROM actions 
                 WHERE date(timestamp) = CURDATE() 
                 GROUP BY kid_id) AS a2 
    ON a2.kid_id = a1.kid_id AND a2.timestamp = a1.timestamp
```

Comment: Sorry but this to returns both of the active values and not the inactive.

Answer (score 0):

use `group by kid_id` which only selects latest row as you have ordered by timestamp

```
SELECT kid_id , status , timestamp FROM actions WHERE date(timestamp) = CURDATE() GROUP BY kid_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: It groups by kid_id before it sorts by timestamp. If I try to group after i have sorted it returns an error. ???

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` like this:

```
 SELECT kid_id , status , timestamp, count(*) as TotalMatches FROM actions WHERE date(timestamp) = CURDATE() GROUP BY kid_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

**[EDIT]**: For selecting only active statuses:

```
 SELECT kid_id , status , timestamp, count(*) as TotalMatches FROM actions WHERE date(timestamp) = CURDATE() AND status = 'active' GROUP BY kid_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: This only selects the active statuses?

Comment: @nickifrandsen, updated the code for selecting only active statuses too.

Comment: I'm sorry i think i might been a little unclear so far. The newest status from kid_id 3 is equal to inactive. Since that's a newer status than the active i want to show the inactive instead...

Imagine a application that's supposed to check if the kid is in the house or if it has left. Then it need to return all kids who are still active and all kids who have been active but has since changed status to inactive. A lot like a login system.

I hope I've been able to explain myself well enough even though my english ain't the best.